# How can simulate Alert Dialog action via onEdtitorActionListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have a custom Alert Dialog that an EditText and positive and negative button to give 4 digits from user. it works fine, but I want to do something that when the user enter 4 digits and click on "DONE" button of soft keyboard, do some codes like positive button and then CLOSE the Dialog. this is my code:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ConversationActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Test");

    final EditText input = new EditText(ConversationActivity.this);

    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                // what should I want.?!
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    int maxLength = 4;
    input.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :-

1) Globally declare alert Dialog instance in your activity

```
..
..
    //Alert Dialog instance
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    int maxLength = 4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

 ..
 ..
```

And use that instance to dismiss your alert dialog

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Test");

                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

                input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                            KeyEvent event) {
                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                            // This is How you do it want.?!
                            if (input.getText().toString().length() == maxLength) {

                                //Use alert Dialog instance to dismiss
                                alertDialog.dismiss();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "You Entered" + input.getText().toString(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Please Enter 4 Digits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                            }

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(
                        maxLength) });

                builder.setView(input);

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You Entered" + input.getText().toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                // This should I want.?!
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });


//Assign alert Dialog instance like this..
                alertDialog = builder.show();
```

Hope this will work for you !